# Как заполнить массив numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, pillow

я пишу программу, которая будет брать `r, g, b, a = img.getpixel(tuple(listss))` и размещать в массив `colors = np.zeros((7, 16))`. Как это сделать? Я не могу ничего с этим поделать. Я мучаюсь над этим вопросом более одной недели и результаты плачевны. Там в присваивании элемента есть недочет. Вот последнее что я напридумывал:

````
    ```
    listss = []
    colors = np.zeros((7, 16))
    right = 0
    down = 0
    downn = 0
    pos_of_sticks = np.zeros((7, 8))
    num_of_iter = 0
    for l in np.nditer(pos_of_sticks):
            num_of_iter += 1
            listss.append(l)
            if num_of_iter == 2:
                print(listss)
                r, g, b, a = img.getpixel(tuple(listss))
                print(r, g, b, a)
                colors[downn, 4*right] = r
                colors[downn, 4*right+1] = g
                colors[downn, 4*right+2] = b
                colors[downn, 4*right+3] = a
                down += 4
                if down == 16:
                    downn += 1
                    down = 0
                listss.clear()
                num_of_iter = 0```
````

Comment: можете доступно объяснить что вы пытаетесь сделать в этом участке кода? Скорее всего это можно сделать проще и элегантнее

Comment: Ок, я беру уже заполненный массив координатами x, y - pos_of_sticks(поэлементно). Далее я подаю две координаты из этого в r, g, b, a = img.getpixel(tuple(listss)). И на выходе получаю цвет данной координаты на скриншоте ... записанных в переменные r, g, b, a. (rgba). Дальше я размещаю эти переменные в массив colors поэлементно(по крайней мере пытаюсь этого добиться)

Comment: Можете пояснить - у вас есть цветная картинка с альфаканалом - что вы хотите получить в итоге?

Comment: Я плохо понимаю что  такое альфа канал, но вроде бы это прозрачность. И от этого отталкиваясь.. Я скажу, что r, g, b, a = img.getpixel(tuple(listss)) без альфа канала(переменной a). Мне выдает ошибку так что так картинка походу с альфа каналом и значение 255. Так что да.

Comment: А в итоге я хочу чтоб в цикле мне делали скриншот и проверяли на изменение цвета эти координаты, а при их изменении делали определенные клики с помощью pyautogui

Comment: Можно просто получать RGB-цвет нужного пикселя на экране с помощью [mss](https://pypi.org/project/mss/), непонятно зачем здесь вообще Pillow и тем более numpy